# Store text data read from a formatted text file to a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list, formatted-input

I'm working on a project for a Student Course Registration System. I'm having problems reading data from a text file and storing it in singly linked list, which has to get updated every time a new student is added. The data is stored in an formatted way. The problem is my struct has type **`char`** variables, so it gives me as Assignment Error.

The struct is defined as:

```
struct Student {
  char stdID[10];
  char stdName[30];
  char stdSemester[5];
  Student  *next; } *Head, *Tail;
```

The code that saves the struct is:

```
// For Saving: 
            SFile << std->stdID << '\t' << std->stdName << '\t' << std->stdSemester << '\n';
```

The code to read the text file and display the struct is:

```
// Display:
system("cls");
cout << "\n\n\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t           LIST OF COURSES" << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t   ====================================================\n" << endl;
cout << "\t" << "ID" << "\t" << setw(15) << "Course Name" << "\n\n";

// Initialize:
char ID[10];
char Name[30];
char Sem[5]; 
ifstream SFile("StudentRecord.txt");
Student *Temp = NULL;

while(!SFile.eof()) {

    // Get:
    SFile.getline(ID, 10, '\t');
    SFile.getline(Name, 30, '\t');
    SFile.getline(Sem, 5, '\t');

    Student *Std = new Student;   //<======== OUCH! Assignment error here
    //node*c=new node;

    // Assign:
    Std->stdID = *ID;

    if (Head == NULL) {
        Head = Std;
    } 
    else {
        Temp = Head;
        {
            while ( Temp->next !=NULL ) {
                Temp=Temp->next;
            }
            Temp->next = Std;
        }
    }
}
SFile.close();
system("pause"); }
```

P.S: I'm Having Problem at Assign Comment;

Will I have to change data type and make the whole project in `string`? I preferred `char` because I was able to format the output, and in `string` i'm sure it reads line by line, so I wont be able stores values from single line.

Comment: `while(!SFile.eof()) {` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use `std::string`?

Comment: `he Problem is my Struct has type "char" variables, so it gives me as Assignment Error` What is an Assignment error?

Comment: ***I preferred char because I was able to format the output,*** char should rarely be preferred over `std::string`. Your program would be simpler if you used `std::string`.

Comment: @drescherjm `Std->stdID = *ID;` is an "assign error".

Comment: @Vikesyy "The Problem is my Struct has type "char" variables" No, it has not. It has members of type *array of `char`*

Comment: @Vikesyy "and in String i'm sure it reads line by line, so I wont be able stores values from single line." you can use `std::string`s much the same way with `getline()` and a delimiter as you do now with `char` arrays.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes, that is what I meant sorry. Do you think I'll have to change the members to String in order to go further on?

Comment: @Vikesyy You don't ***have to***, but it would make your life easier.

Comment: You could use a c-string function to copy the c-string. Although with `std::string` the assignment with `=` would just work..

Comment: @Vikeyy: With "`Std->stdID = *ID;`" you are trying to assign a `char` (`*ID (the same as `ID[0]`)) to an *array of `char`*. This won't work because arrays dont have value semantics in C++. You'd have to use `std::strcpy()` to copy `ID` to `Std->stdID`.

Comment: @Swordfish So I'll be able to achieve it by the following; getline(cin, ID, "\t"); ?

Comment: Okay Thank You @Swordfish this was really helpful, I'll research a bit.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you!

Comment: @Vikesyy `std::getline(the_ifstream_you_want_to_read_from, your_std_string, '\t');`

Answer (score 1):

### To use strings ?

If IDs would be `std:string`, you could do:

```
Std->stdID = ID;
```

And you could use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
getline(SFile, ID, '\t');
```

You wouldn't have to worry about maximum length,  but you could still decide to check the lngth of the string and shorten it if necessary.

### Or not to use strings ?

But if you prefer (or have to) to use `char[]` instead, then you need to use the [`strncpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) for doing assignments :

```
strncpy( Std->stdID, ID, 10 );  // Std->stdID = *ID;
```

Honnestly, in the 21st century, I'd go for std::string, and not stick to the old `char[]` that date back to the 70s...

### File loop

It's unrelated, but you should never loop on `eof`:

```
while (SFile.getline(ID, 10, '\t') 
     && SFile.getline(Name, 30, '\t')  && SFile.getline(Sem, 5, '\n') {
   ...
}
```

Why ?  Look [here for more explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/3723423)

And by the way, your last `getline()` should certainly look for `'\n'` as delimiter, according to your writing function.

Comment: `Std->stdID = ID`

Comment: I actually don't understand "eof", like can you explain  how its un-related. Sorry I'm new to programming.

Comment: @Vikesyy by "its unrealeated" Christophe wanted to say that what he mentions about your use of `eof` is unrelated to what you are asking about. You should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @Christophe Thank You Means A lot!

Comment: @Christophe If I dont want to use Stream Size, Only Limiters, will I be able to Get all input from Text file?

Comment: @Vikesyy no, it will stop at first delimiter